# UITableView: Same cell, Multiple model objects(MVC)

Tags: ios, uitableview, design-patterns, model-view-controller, uicollectionview

I was doing research on writing modular clean code while working with `UITableView` & `UICollectionView` and I found nice blog on writing lighter ViewControllers by [Objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/table-views/). While following practices given by author I came up with a paragraph which says about `Same Cell type and Multiple Model Object` not in detail, just descriptive.
I just wanted to ask does anyone suggest how we could achieve this in better more modular way?
The paragraph says something like this,

`In cases where we have multiple model objects that can be presented using the same cell type, we can even go one step further to gain reusability of the cell. First, we define a protocol on the cell to which an object must conform in order to be displayed by this cell type. Then we simply change the configure method in the cell category to accept any object conforming to this protocol. These simple steps decouple the cell from any specific model object and make it applicable to different data types.`

Can anyone explain what it meant?
I know it is off topic but it may help someone writing better code.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to introducing ViewModel or ViewAdapter. A simple example of this is a cell displays description of any item. Say if you give the cell a User, it displays his/her full name. If you give a Mail, it displays the subject. The point is that the cell does not care what exactly given to it (a user or a mail). It only need description of every item so it needs **something that help it extract description string from every single model of different types**. That's the ViewModel.

Then instead of: Cell => User or Cell => News. Use: Cell => ViewModel => User or Cell => ViewModel => News. Code sample:

```
class ViewModel {

    private Object _item;

    public ViewModel(Object item) {
        _item = item;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        if (_item instanceof User) {
            return ((User)_item).getFullName();
        } else if (_item instanceof Mail) {
            return ((Mail)_item).getSubject();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Here it is not telling to write conditional code depending upon type of model.
Here it is asking for declaring some interface (in java terms) or protocol (in ObjC terms).

Comment: Same concept, different ways of implementation. The snippet above is one of the most simple way using Adapter. I thought you just wanted to get the idea...